# Uninitialized constant Capybara::Webkit::Configuration

Tags: rspec, capybara-webkit

I have an issue due adding the [puffing-billy](https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy) to my capybara-webkit features. 
I followed by instructions:

rails_helper.rb:

```
require 'billy/capybara/rspec'
```

capybara.rb:

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit_billy
#and other staff bellow
```

Due running feature I have:

```
NameError:
            uninitialized constant Capybara::Webkit::Configuration
          # /Users/ir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@guestready/gems/puffing-billy-0.11.1/lib/billy/browsers/capybara.rb:43:in `block in register_webkit_driver'
          # /Users/ir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@guestready/gems/capybara-2.17.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:101:in `driver'
```

What I m missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because you're using a very old version of capybara-webkit.  If you don't need the latest Capybara lock the version of capybara-webkit in your Gemfile to ~>1.14 (latest release)   If you do need the latest Capybara you'll have to tell your Gemfile to use the master branch of capybara-webkit.

Comment: Yep, in my gemfile it was just `gem 'capybara-webkit'` without version. And event after `bundle update capybara-webkit` it still used old `1.1.0`. To fix I set the version manually `gem 'capybara-webkit', '~> 1.14.0'` and only after it new version has been loaded.

Comment: @IvanRostovsky It was selecting the old version because bundler had decided to use the latest version of Capybara which capybara-webkit 1.14.0 isn't marked as compatible with.  Therefore bundler went back in versions to find a version of capybara-webkit which was marked as compatible with the latest version of Capybara - which happens to be 1.1.0.  This is caused by very conservative specification of compatibility since then on the capybara-webkit gem.  The master branch of `capybara-webkit` may be better for you to use - `gem 'capybara-webkit', github: 'thoughbot/capybara-webkit'`

Comment: @IvanRostovsky capybara-webkit 1.15.0 was just released which does support the latest Capybara and should fix all these issues.